# Filter a pivot with wildcards without iteration

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I want to set report filters so a pivot will only include a certain word using wildcards.

Excel pivot rows (xlRowField in VBA) can be filtered with PivotFilters.Add2, for example,

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("RowField").PivotFilters.Add2 _
Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="this"
```

But I need to filter report f(xlPageField in VBA). I know I can iterate the pivotitems:

```
For i = 1 To PivotItems.Count
    If PivotItems(i) Like "*this*" Then
            PivotItems(i).Visible = true
    else
            PivotItems(i).Visible = false
    End If
next
```

But I'm talking about a very large data set, in which iteration takes forever, while a GUI filtering takes no more than a second:

[image][image]

I tried to record a GUI filtering into a macro, and it turns out Excel just recorded a manual filtering, as if I went to each item manually and checked it.

**Demo data set**

```
----------------------------
| Name    | Class | Grade  |
----------------------------
| Joe     |   B1   | 100   |
----------------------------
| Steve   |   B2   | 80    |
----------------------------
| Rebecca |   C    | 99    |
----------------------------
| Sharon  |   D    | 78    |
----------------------------
```

You can download it as CSV:

```
Name,Class,Grade
Joe,B1,100
Steve,B2,80
Rebecca,C,99
Sharon,D,78
```

**Demo Pivot**

```
-------------------------------------
| Class | (Multiple Items) e.g. B*  | How do I do it without iteration?
-------------------------------------

---------------------------------
| Row Labels  |   Sum of Grade  |
---------------------------------
| Joe         |       100       |
---------------------------------
| Steve       |       80        |
---------------------------------
| Grand Total |       180       |
---------------------------------
```

Comment: What's wrong with `sumifs`?

Comment: sumifs are nice for fast calculations. But when you have lots of rows, values and report filters, Pivots are way more suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will be faster (although I haven't tested it on a large dataset).

Make a range called "searchText" on a sheet somewhere.

Put a column called, "helper" at the end of your dataset.

Put the formula:

```
  =NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(searchText,B2)))
```

in your helper column, where B represents the column with the data you are searching for.

Use this code:

```
Dim shtSearch As Worksheet
Dim shtPivot As Worksheet
Dim myPivot As PivotTable
Dim helperPF As PivotField

Set shtSearch = Sheets("Sheet1")
shtSearch.Range("searchText").Value = "b" 'put in whatever you are searching for.

Set shtPivot = Sheets("Sheet4")
Set myPivot = shtPivot.PivotTables("myPivot")
Set helperPF = myPivot.PivotFields("helper")

With helperPF
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With

helperPF.CurrentPage = "TRUE"

myPivot.PivotCache.Refresh
```

Comment: It's a fast as a GUI filtering! I assume by "sh" you meant "shtSearch". But there's no need to create a range if you already put the filtering pattern in another cell. I also think it's better to use iserror over isnumber because it seems more proper to me to catch errors by using iserror:  `=not(iserror(SEARCH('another_sheet'!a1, B2)))`

Comment: Yep, that was a typo.  Agreed that iserror is a better option.  I'll update.  I didn't know how your code was implemented, so just left a way to change the range.  If the user is already putting it into a cell, it doesn't matter, but if they were putting it into a form, I was thinking it would need to get put into the sheet.

Comment: Consider marking this as the answer if this solves the issue.  Obviously, feel free to leave it if you are looking for another answer that may show how to replicate Excel's searching functionality.